# PHP Fatal Error can't use function return value in write context

Tags: php

I am working on a PHP project and doing the development on Windows and everything works perfectly fine.

When I install the code onto a Linux box the page breaks and I get the following error:

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Can't use function return value in write context
```

The line that this error is referring to is

```
if (!isset(parent::getPostArray()["searchRefOnly"]))
```

And all the `parent::getPostarray()` function does is return an array as follows:

```
protected function getPostArray()
        {
            return $this->postArray;
        }
```

The above code works perfectly fine on Windows, so why not on Linux?

Comment: perhaps different php version? also it's duplicate

Comment: Duplication, solution is to upgrade to a higher PHP version. Works in PHP 5.5 and above.

Comment: How is that a duplicate, that is referring to the empty function so they are trying to make a change. I'm not writing any changes I'm just checking if a value in a returned array exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this way

```
$result = $this->getPostArray();//parent::getPostArray()
if (!empty($result)){}
```